# Error while compiling librealsense in clion

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, clion, realsense

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and I wanted to integrate the "Intel Reale Sense Library" into clion.

So i strictly followed the instructions on: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/installation.md

Then I installed Clion and edited the CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(PAE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(PAE ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(PAE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "~/librealsense/CMake/")
find_package(LibUSB REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LibUSB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${LibUSB_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(PAE ${LIBS})
```

But when I try to build I get the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/PAE.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion `rs_apply_depth_control_preset(rs_device*, int)':
/usr/local/include/librealsense/rsutil.h:85: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `rs_set_device_options'
MakeFiles/PAE.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion `rs_apply_ivcam_preset(rs_device*, rs_ivcam_preset)':
/usr/local/include/librealsense/rsutil.h:128: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `rs_reset_device_options_to_default'
/usr/local/include/librealsense/rsutil.h:132: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `rs_set_device_options'
/usr/local/include/librealsense/rsutil.h:133: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `rs_set_device_options'
/usr/local/include/librealsense/rsutil.h:134: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `rs_set_device_options'
```

This is my test-code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <librealsense/rs.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat image;
    image = imread("/home/philip/Bilder/r200.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if(! image.data )                          
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   

    waitKey(0);                                          
    return 0;
}
```

I'm a Linux-Newbie, so I don't know what the reason for the error could be. I rechecked all the settings I've made but I cannot find the error.

Comment: In your `CMakeLists.txt` file you never tell CMake that you need to link with the Real Sense library. Only with the USB library dependency. That looks, by the way, like an internal CMake file that librealsense uses for its own configuration and build process. You should probably build librealsense separately and *install* it, then use the installed libraries and header files.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It worked !

Comment: very helpful comment !